# Ckeditor images use different image sizes based on device screen size

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

For images embedded into the Ckeditor body. I want images to load that have been specifically sized for the user screen based on breakpoints. Just like the Responsive Images module in Drupal 8. Is this possible? This module comes with core but is not enabled by default and it only works with fielded images. This seems to be on the right track https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/imageresponsive

Comment: The only way you’re going to get this easily is using Media Entities and embedding them with Entity Embed. Then you can render media and use responsive image formatters, and twig template for markup.

Comment: @Kenin 7 Thank you. We are using Entity Embed to place images into Ckeditor. In the page template I render the body like this: {{ content.body }} So it just dumps the body on the page. I know how to set up Responsive Image Styles for fielded images by switching the field formatter to Responsive Image and setting up a Responsive Image style that selects different Image styles for each breakpoint, But How do I set a field format for an image inside Ckeditor?

Comment: Because the entities should be rendered- the Embed dialog should give you a drop down option of what image style to use.

Comment: Yes your right, in Ckeditor you can select which image style you want to use when embedding the image. The problem is that image style is used for all device screen sizes, sm, md , and lg. The Drupal Responsive Image module allows fielded images to display different Image styles depending on the device screen size that is viewing the content. it saves bandwidth when you are able to display a small 10kb version of a photo for mobile device and a large 200kb version for desktop device. I dont think this is possible to do inside Ckeditor.

Comment: Yeah, but if you hook it up so that instead of selecting Image Style, that you can select a View Mode of media, you can then set the image formatter in that view mode to be Responsive Image with the style set of your choosing. The Lightning distro has this option, I am not sure what provides it. But I just set that up on a project I am working on and it works.